# logout of keycloak gatekeeper using python requests sessions

Tags: python, keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper

### using browser

everything works find if i login and logout using the browser

eg. i login using the keycloak form
and i logout by pasting the following in the browser

```
{}/oauth/logout?redirect={}/auth/realms/{}/protocol/openid-connect/logout
```

when i check the keycloak admin page, the session is removed as expected

### using python requests sessions

i login using the following

```py
r = self.session.post(
    "{}/oauth/login".format(self.host),
    data={"username": username, "password": password},
    verify=False
)
```

this works and when i try to access any endpoints i am able to after login

i logout using the following

```py
url = "{}/oauth/logout?redirect={}/auth/realms/{}/protocol/openid-connect/logout".format(
    self.host,
    self.host,
    self.realm_name
)
r = self.session.get(
    url,
    allow_redirects=True,
    verify=False,
)
```

this logs me out of gatekeeper and clears the cookies (i cant acccess and endpoints which is correct), however in the keycloak admin page, i still see my session active.

the cookies should have been kept in the session, anyone knows why? thanks

Edit:

i think its because when i login through gatekeeper using the endpoint

```
/oauth/login
```

it does not return these 3 cookies which i get when i use the browser

```
AUTH_SESSION
KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY
KEYCLOAK_SESSION
```

these 3 cookies come from the endpoint

```
https://{}/auth/realms/{}/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

however, since i dont login through the form, i dont have these tokens